# Cambio el formato de una fecha dmy a Y-m-d

Tags: php, date

Tengo esta fecha **`08092020`** y quiero cambiarlo a 2020-09-08 ya he intentado de varias maneras, pero quisiera hacerlo de la forma mas corta posible.

tambien habia intentando usar

```
$fecha = "08092020"; 
$mi_fecha = substr($fecha, 0, 2) . '-' . substr($fecha, 2, 2) . '-' . substr($fecha, 4);
```

Comment: esa fecha es un string, he intentado cambiar de formato usando el date(), tambien con el strtotime, pero ese valor no es reconocible por esas funciones como una fecha

Comment: tambien habia intentando usar el sbstr, $fecha = "08092020";
        $mi_fecha = substr($fecha, 0, 2) . '-' . substr($fecha, 2, 2) . '-' . substr($fecha, 4); , de todas formas, muchas gracias por la ayuda, voy a usar el date_parse_from_format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta realizar esto:

```
$fecha = '08092020';
$arr = date_parse_from_format("dmY", $fecha);
echo $arr['year'].'-'.str_pad($arr['month'],2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'-'.str_pad($arr['day'],2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

`date_parse_from_format` obtiene la información de la fecha segun el formato que tenga, para este caso era `dmY`.

Esta función genera un array con siguiente información:

```
Array ( [year] => 2020 [month] => 9 [day] => 8 [hour] => [minute] => [second] => [fraction] => [warning_count] => 0 [warnings] => Array ( ) [error_count] => 0 [errors] => Array ( ) [is_localtime] => )
```

Luego solo queda imprimir la fecha según el formato que indicas, dado que algunos números le faltan ceros a la izquierda, estos se rellenan con `str_pad`

### Mejor Solución

Aplicando la función `date_create_from_format` obtenemos la fecha del string segun el formato indicado (`dmY`), luego lo imprimimos con `date_format` con el formato deseado.

```
$fecha = '08092020';
$fecha_format = date_create_from_format("dmY", $fecha);
echo date_format($fecha_format, 'Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Lo ideal sería esperar a ver que ha intentado el OP ya que si no le pueden cerrar la pregunta

Comment: Por otro lado con `createFormFormat` parece ser suficiente incluso usando `format` pues veo totalmente innecesario el uso de str_pad

Answer (score 1):

El formato de la fecha de tu string no parece ser alguno de los válidos<sup>1</sup>, entonces nos podemos valer del método estático [**`createFormFormat`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) de la clase [**`DateTime`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php), de esta forma:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

$fechaSinFormato = '08092020';

$fechaFormateada = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $fechaSinFormato);

echo $fechaFormateada->format('Y-m-d');
```

Con una salida así:

> 2020-09-08

- Le pasamos el string de la *fecha* y le indicamos el formato que parece tener
- Como salida nos retorna un objeto de la clase `DateTime`
- Posterior usamos el método [`format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) para indicar el formato que tendrá la fecha de salida (*aqui recomiendo leas el enlace para ver las banderas permitidas al momento de construir el formato*)
- <sup>1</sup>Recomiendo [leas aqui sobre los formatos de fecha/tiempo válidos para el parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php)